# How to define an open set in the context of topology?

Tags: general-topology

$T$ is said to be a topology on a set $X$ if:

1. Both, the empty set and $X$ open.
2. Any finite intersection of open sets is open.
3. Arbitrary union of open sets is open.

$T$ is said to be a topology on a set $X$ if:

1. Both, the empty set and $X$ are in $T$.
2. $T$ is closed under finite intersection.
3. $T$ is closed under arbitrary union.

I believe that any member of the topology is said to be an open set (after reading both the above-stated definitions) and that would make perfect sense in an example like $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $T=\{\phi, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, X\}$. What happens if $T$ doesn't form a topology? Let's say $T$ were $\{\phi, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, X\}$ (${a,b}$ intersection $\{a,c\}$ does not belong to $T$). Will I still say that the members of $T$ are all open sets.

Is it the case that an open set is any subset of $X$ instead of a member of the topology.

(Excuse me for not including mathematical symbols, I'm fairly new to the site and I don't know how to do that).

Comment: Be definition a set is open if and only if it is a member of the topology.

Comment: Topology is just a collection of subsets . The members of that collection are termed as "open" sets. So a topology is the collection of subsets of a set $X$ which you want to be open and which obeys certain rules(like arbitrary union of such subsets must also be in your collection(topology) and also finite intersections and the entire set $X$ and the null set must also be there) . So for example I can just say that given a set $X$, I can define "a topology" on it by declaring that $T=\{\phi,X\}$.

Comment: Thanks to you both for clearing it up <3